# Finding a bound on the integral of function of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently trying to show that an function has a finite integral. I am trying to find the iterated integral of:

$$
\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}
$$

over $-\infty < \alpha, \beta <\infty$.

I am able to see that $\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}} < e^{|\alpha + 0.3\beta|}$, and that $\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}} < e^{|\alpha + 0.05\beta|}$.

Hence, I have that:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.3\beta}}\frac{e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha + 0.05\beta}} d\alpha d\beta
$$

$$
< \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{|\alpha + 0.3\beta|} e^{|\alpha + 0.05\beta|}d\alpha d\beta
$$

However, I am not sure where to proceed from here. One option seems to be doing the Jacobian and using a transformation. Is there any easy way to bound this integral? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We transform coordinates with

$$x=\alpha +0.3\beta$$

$$y=\alpha+0.05\beta$$

Then, the Jacobian of transformation is $4$, and the integral of interest $I$ is

$$\begin{align}
I=&4\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x}}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2}\frac{e^y}{\left(1+e^y\right)^2}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=4\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}\, du\right)^2\\\\
&=4
\end{align}$$

Comment: I get the Jacobian equal to $-1/4.$ But that's a great way to do it!

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the catch. +1 Actually, the Jacobian is $4$ as this transform is $(\alpha,\beta)\to(x,y)$ and we need to take the absolute value of the determinant.

Comment: I was referring to $\partial (x,y)/\partial (\alpha, \beta).$ The term "Jacobian" to me is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix. We take the absolute value of the Jacobian to change variables.

Comment: @zhw. Yes. You are correct.  I actually think of the Jacobian as the matrix. And the tranform involves the absolute value of its determinant.

Comment: would there be any problems with the limits of integration? Meaning, how would I change the limits according to the transformation? I'm not quite sure how they are still infinity. Thanks!

Comment: @user123276 There are no problems.  Take any rectangle in $(\alpha,\beta)$ that contains the origin (not necessarily centered).  You should be able to show that as that rectangle grows without bound, that the mapped coordinates $(x,y)$ will span the entire $(x,y)$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

I would separate the regions so that you know which sign the absolute values take and integrate directly. It's somewhat tediuos but will be exact instead of the upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to separate the regions before but the fact that I kept getting undefined integrals was part of the reason I tried to use a transformation. For example, assuming $|\alpha + 0.3\beta| > 0$ and $|\alpha + 0.05\beta| > 0$, then the first integral has $e^{2\alpha}$, which leads to an infinite value. Do you mind if you elaborated on what you mean with region separation? Thanks!